# Count how many times the data appear in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

i have a field which name is “account”  and its varchar type,this field have data that can repeat or can only apear once, i need that other field called “consecutive” counts how many times does the data in “account” apears, i can’t do it manually because i have  lots of data.

This is an example of what i have

```
Account Consecutive
24590   1
24590   1
23789   1
23789   1
23789   1
98789   1
98789   1
89768   1
89768   1
15678   1
15678   1
14356   1
```

This is what i need
Account Consecutive

```
24590   1
24590   2
23789   1
23789   2
23789   3
98789   1
```

Comment: If it is sql-server, then it cannot be plsql and vice versa. Please correct your tag.

Comment: Can you post something so we have an idea of what you really have? Unformatted text like this is impossible to figure out what you have. Are those rows, multiple columns, or some form of delimited data. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Well gosh with a little formatting it appears these are rows. You can user ROW_NUMBER quite painlessly.

Comment: If this was indeed sqlServer you can use a PARTITION BY

Comment: ive got this guys

declare no_cuenta NUMERIC;
declare conta numeric
set conta=0;
DECLARE c_consecutivo CURSOR FOR 
SELECT no_cuenta
FROM [dbo].[BC_3259_dup_prueba]

OPEN c_consecutivo
      FETCH NEXT FROM c_consecutivo INTO no_cuenta
      WHILE FETCH_STATUS = 0 
      BEGIN
                  
      
      UPDATE [dbo].[BC_3259_dup_prueba]
                   SET consecutivo= CASE WHEN no_cuenta = no_cuenta THEN conta +1 else 2  END

            
FETCH NEXT FROM c_consecutivo INTO no_cuenta   
                
END -- De BEGIN
CLOSE c_consecutivo
DEALLOCATE c_consecutivo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have much to work with here but pretty sure you need something along these lines. (This of course assumes that you are using sql-server)

```
select Account
    , Consecutive = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Account, order by (select null))
from SomeTable
```